# Error in connecting ms access 2013 database with vb.net application

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I am having trouble connecting my mdb database. I am trying to add some data from form into the database but as i run the application and click on add button, it shows following error:-
"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" "cmd was nothing". This is my code :-

```
Public Class addForm
Dim cnn As OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
Private Sub addForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Try
        cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\krish\source\repos\DDC Library Management System\DDC Library Management System\bin\Debug\data.accdb"
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Books(BookType,BookCode,BookName,Publication,Price,Author,dt)VALUES(@bookType, @bookCode, @bookName, @publication, @price, @author, @dt)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookType", bookType.SelectedItem)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookCode", bookCode.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookName", bookName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publication", txtPublication.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", txtPrice.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", txtAuthor.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dtDate.Value)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnn.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Data Added")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub End Class
```

'addForm' is the name of my current form.

[This is the error it is showing as soon as i click on ADD Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mmbo.jpg)

Comment: Where do you assign an object to `cmd`?

Comment: You are trying to use a Null object when you call the object "cmd". Add this line after Try directly to create the object first `cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand`

Comment: You can get Visual Studio to write all this code for you, by the way..

Comment: @CaiusJard How so? How can i get visual studio to write all this code? Please tell me, it will help a lot

Comment: @KrishnaSaxena for example https://youtu.be/zrtjZlTYLQA - there is a lot more than can be covered in 9 minutes, but if you were to do that process in the video, then VS would have written all the code like above and more..